# touch.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: touch, editor, nano

PS C:\projects\Node Series\2-ExpressServer> touch index2.js
touch : File C:\Program Files\nodejs\touch.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.                                                                                                                                                                                            LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- touch index2.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In Vs Code change the terminal from powershell to cmd prompt, the issue will be resolved.
[image]

Comment: needs editing, and clarifications, plus another post must be merged or removed from this question